# Problem with fetch: '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: json, api, flutter, rest, dart

I'm trying to fetch data from an API, but I keep getting this error.

> Problem with fetch: '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List'

Please tell me how to fix this code.

Model.dart

```
class ComprovanteModel {
  ComprovantesInfoModel jsonResponse;

  String error;

  ComprovanteModel({this.jsonResponse, this.error});

  ComprovanteModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : jsonResponse = ComprovantesInfoModel.fromJson(json['json_response']),
        error = '';

  ComprovanteModel.withError(String errorValue)
      : jsonResponse = null,
        error = errorValue;
}

class ComprovanteInfoModel {
  String clientFormalName;
  int volumes;
  int duration;
  CheckpointsModel checkpoint;

  ComprovanteInfoModel({
    this.clientFormalName,
    this.duration,
    this.volumes,
    this.checkpoint,
  });

  ComprovanteInfoModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : clientFormalName = json['client_formal_name'],
        checkpoint = CheckpointsModel.fromJson(json['checkpoint']),
        volumes = json['volumes'],
        duration = json['duration'];
}

class CheckpointModel {
  int checkpointId;
  String arrivalTime;
  int status;

  CheckpointModel({
    this.checkpointId,
    this.arrivalTime,
    this.status,
  });

  CheckpointModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : checkpointId = json['checkpoint_id'],
        arrivalTime = json['arrival_time'],
        status = json['status'];
}

class CheckpointsModel {
  List<CheckpointModel> checkpoint;

  CheckpointsModel({this.checkpoint});

  CheckpointsModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> jsonList)
      : checkpoint = jsonList.map((e) => CheckpointModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
}
```

The API response:

```
{
  "json_response": [
    {
      "client_formal_name": "",
      "deadline": null,
      "volumes": 1,
      "duration": 5,
      "depot_id": 20,
      "service_id": 109856,
      "georef_provider": "ap_geocoder",
      "checkpoint": {
        "checkpoint_id":,
        "arrival_time": "",
        "duration":,
        "status": 1,
        "event_id": 5,
        "resources": [
          {
            "content_type": "PHOTO",
            "service_event_effect_id": 58,
            "content": "em+ndG6XtE2unp",
            "content_label": "",
            "user_effect_unique_code": ""
          },
          {
            "content_type": "RECEPTOR_INFO",
            "service_event_effect_id": 61,
            "content": "{\"user_relationship_unique_code\":\"\",\"is_expected_receiver\":\"true\",\"document\":\"65979973000240\",\"name\":\"",\"description\":\"",\"id\":\"1\"}",
            "content_label": "",
            "user_effect_unique_code": "2"
          }
        ],
        "event_description": "",
        "operation_date": "",
        "obs": "",
        "is_assistant": false,
        "image": "{\"description\": \"Documento\", \"photo\": \""}"
      },
      "final_attendance_window_b": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to access the checkpoint item, then the resource item(which I think is the same process as the checkpoint). I am using the list but I don't think is right, I am suppose to use map but I don't know how. Please show me a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change this:

  ```
  ComprovanteModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : jsonResponse = ComprovantesInfoModel.fromJson(json['json_response']),
        error = '';
  ```

To this:

```
 ComprovanteModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : jsonResponse = ComprovantesInfoModel.fromJson(json['json_response'][0]), //added [0] here.
        error = '';
```

- If you look closely at your response, it does have the map that you need, but this map is actually inside a list, notice the square brackets [ ] around the {} in `"json_response": [`.

The map that you need to access, is at index[0] of this list, then everything will work fine.

Second thing, this:

```
 CheckpointsModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> jsonList)
      : checkpoint = jsonList.map((e) => CheckpointModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
}
```

- You are telling Flutter that you will pass an object of type `List<dynamic>` , but in the json you post, `"checkpoint": {` is not a list, it's a map. But even so, this map has only one checkpoint.
- To answer your last question

> I wanna access the checkpoint item, then the resource item(wich i
> think is the same process as the checkpoint).

`"resources": [` is indeed a list of Maps. In your code you did not post your resources model, but I'm assuming you want a `List<Resources>` and not `List<CheckPoint>`, it'll look like this:

```
class SingleResourceModel {
   String contentType;
   int serviceId;
   String content;
   String contentLabel;
   String uniqueCode;

  SingleResourceModel({
    this.contentType,
    this.serviceId,
    this.content,
    this.contentLabel,
    this.uniqueCode
  });

  SingleResourceModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : contentType = json['content_type'],
        serviceId = json['service_event_effect_id'],
        content = json['content'];
        contentLabel = json['content_label'],
        uniqueCode = json['user_effect_unique_code'];
}
class ListResourceModel {
  List<SingleResourceModel> resourcesList;

  ListResourceModel({this.resourcesList});

  ListResourceModel.fromJson(List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonList)
      : resourcesList = jsonList.map((e) => SingleResourceModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
}
```

Finally, you can modify your `CheckPoint` model, and add to it a `ListResourceModel`, to look like this in the end:

```
class CheckpointModel {
  int checkpointId;
  String arrivalTime;
  int status;
  ListResourceModel resourcesList;

  CheckpointModel({
    this.checkpointId,
    this.arrivalTime,
    this.status,
    this.resourcesList
  });

  CheckpointModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : checkpointId = json['checkpoint_id'],
        arrivalTime = json['arrival_time'],
        status = json['status'],
        resourcesList= json['resources'];    
   }
```

Now, you should be all set.